# Cubesat communication services

Tags: communication, cubesat, communication-satellite

Is there any known web-based API services that provide downlink/uplink testing facilities to some Cubesat?

I don't want to have full hardware setup: antenna, sdr, auxiliary equipment. In same time, I want to test specific DSP algoritms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the closest answer to your question is [Satnogs](https://satnogs.org/).
Other similar projects are

- [Genso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Educational_Network_for_Satellite_Operations)
- [Leaf Line](http://www.leafspace.eu/leaf-line/) (commercial, I don't think they'll release an API in the short term)

Comment: Nice! Not exactly what I wanted, but close enough