# Does every satellite operator build and operate their own ground station?

Tags: artificial-satellite, ground-station

I'm thinking especially of small-time operators. Like if a high school team puts a cubesat into space, do they also put an antenna on the school building and just put up with limited accessibility when the cubesat is over the horizon? Or is there some Groundstations'R'Us provider that could offer access to a wider network?

Answer (score 7):

Creating your own station does not present a particular technical problem and does not require special technical knowledge.

By creating one station connected to the satnogs.org network, you get access to the monitoring time at other stations of this network.  https://network.satnogs.org

You can also take advantage of the Amazon offer - AWS Ground station  https://aws.amazon.com/ru/ground-station/?hp=tile&so-exp=below

More about satnogs.org and other networks:

- [How does the Satellite Networked Open Ground Station operate? How is it used?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24471/12102)
- [What kind of transmitters and antennas do the Lightsail-2 ground stations use?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37119/12102)
- [Cubesat communication services](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8465/12102)

P.S. add SatNOGS Ground Station Building Guide video

Comment: Those are both fascinating! The popular literature never seems to cover this part of the space business, but there must be more to be covered than I had thought.

Comment: @Greg I've added some more links

Comment: @A.Rumlin I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @uhoh Thanks, this is excellent! Like I hinted at, it seems to be under-discussed in the literature. All kinds of books will tell you all kinds of things about launchers and sensors and power supplies, but not much about that whole slew of details like licensing, communicating, integration, or ground stations. It's not like I've never picked up a book or two on the subject, but I never knew these things existed. It's very exciting, it's making space available to Mr. Everyman.